# Accessing Task Queue REST API from APIs Explorer

Tags: php, api, google-app-engine, rest, google-api-php-client

I want to use the Task Queue REST API in my GAE hosted php application but I keep getting:

```
403 Forbidden

Cache-Control:  private, max-age=0
Content-Encoding:  gzip
Content-Length:  146
Content-Type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date:  Tue, 01 Jul 2014 19:16:21 GMT
Expires:  Tue, 01 Jul 2014 19:16:21 GMT
Server:  GSE

{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "forbidden",
"message": "you are not allowed to make this api call"
}
],
"code": 403,
"message": "you are not allowed to make this api call"
}
}
```

I tried apis-explorer at https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/taskqueue/v1beta2/ but (for example) at taskqueue.tasks.list method
I enter project "name of my GAE php application", taskqueue default and I get the same 403 as before.

The documentation says:
Activate the Google App Engine Task Queue in the Google Developers Console. (If the API isn't listed in the Developers Console, then skip this step.)

The API isn't listed.

Any ideas ?